# Code Mirror Get Current Line Number every time content changes

Tags: javascript, html, css, codemirror

I am trying to use Code Mirror to create a text editor. I want to show the current line number to the user at the bottom of the display, as text editors do.

So far I have tried this:

```
function updateInfo(){
var lines = editor.lineCount();
document.getElementById('line-no.').innerText = lines;
editor.refresh();
}
editor.on("change", updateInfo());
```

The `line-no.` is a `span` where I want to display the Line Number. This works for the first Line Number but then when I go to some other line, it doesn't do anything. The console shows this error:

```
codemirror.js:2154 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
at codemirror.js:2154
at fireCallbacksForOps (codemirror.js:2111)
at finishOperation (codemirror.js:2125)
at endOperation (codemirror.js:3747)
at HTMLTextAreaElement.<anonymous> (codemirror.js:3884)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update**

> To follow updates in the editor, register a handler on the [`cursorActivity`](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#event_doc_cursorActivity) event. This event is fired when there is a change in the cursor or selection. 
> The handler is called with the instance of CodeMirror; on this you can call the [`getCursor`](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#getCursor) method to be the an object that contains the current line number that the cursor is active on.
>   **Note that** the line number is zero-based, so you may or may not increment it by 1.

```
const STATUS_CURRENT_LINE = document.getElementById('line-no.');

const onCursorActivity = (instance) => {
  const cursor = cm.getCursor();
  STATUS_CURRENT_LINE.textContent = cursor.line + 1;
}

editor.on("cursorActivity", onCursorActivity);
```

---

#### Setting the current line number when there is a doc change in the editor

The error happens because the `updateInfo` callback is called even before you register it. So that the value registered as the callback is `undefined`.

```
editor.on('change', updateInfo()) // -> editor.on('change', undefined)
```

This can be resolved by registering the function.

```
editor.on('change', updateInfo)
```

However, the signature for the callback should follow what is documented.

[The `change` callback](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#events) is passed the `instance` of CodeMirror and a `changeObject` from which you can retrieve the current line.

> `"change" (instance: CodeMirror, changeObj: object)`
>   Fires every time the content of the editor is changed. The `changeObj` is a `{from, too, text, removed, origin}` object containing information about the changes that occurred as the second argument. `from` and `to` are the positions (in the pre-change coordinate system) where the change started and ended (for example, it might be `{ch:0, line:18}` if the position is at the beginning of line #19). `text` is an array of strings representing the text that replaced the changed range (split by line). `removed` is the text that used to be between `from` and `to`, which is overwritten by this change. This event is fired before the end of an operation before the DOM updates happen.

```
const STATUS_CURRENT_LINE = document.getElementById('line-no.');

function updateInfo(instance, changeObj){
   STATUS_CURRENT_LINE.innerText = changeObj.to.line;
}

editor.on("change", updateInfo);
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much! The explanation was awesome and it works as intended!

Comment: You can listen on `cursorActivity` event. I'll update my answer in a bit to show an example

Comment: No need, figured it out myself. Thanks Anyways!

Comment: Glad that you figured that out!